# Image resize on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I am missing something here:

```
<!-- image is 1920 × 1080 pixels (W x H) -->
<a href="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png/"><img alt="postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png/" onmouseover="iyu3Pheu(this)" onmouseout="Xio8Hogh(this)" border="0" src="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png" width="300" style="padding-left:1px;"></a>
<script>
  function iyu3Pheu(x) {
    if(x.style.width < 500){
      x.style.width = "50%";
    }
    else {
      x.style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
  function Xio8Hogh(x) {
    x.style.width = "300px";
  }
</script>
```

The issue is I need to mouseover the image twice to get the properly resized `onmouseover` image (the first `onmouseover`, presumably, to get the image dimensions).  What am I missing?

Here is a JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/tesesi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `x.style.width` is returning nothing the first time you mouse over the image since you're not defining the width in the style tag(it works the second time because on mouseout you are defining the width in CSS using the `Xio8Hogh` function). All you need to do is move the width into the CSS instead of using the `width` attribute.

A couple of suggestions: Firstly, name your functions in a way that they explain what the function will do rather than just gibberish. This will make it easier for you to debug and if you are working in a team, it will make it easier for your team members to understand what your code is doing. Also, try defining your CSS in a stylesheet rather than inline in the HTML. This will make your code cleaner.

```html
<!-- image is 1920 × 1080 pixels (W x H) -->
<a href="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png/"><img alt="postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png/" onmouseover="iyu3Pheu(this)" onmouseout="Xio8Hogh(this)" border="0" src="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png" style="width:300px;padding-left:1px;"></a>
<script>
  function iyu3Pheu(x) {
    if(x.style.width < 500){
      x.style.width = "50%";
    }
    else {
      x.style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
  function Xio8Hogh(x) {
    x.style.width = "300px";
  }
</script>
```

With that out of the way, I also wanted to mention that this functionality can be done entirely in CSS without any need for JavaScript like so:

```css
img {
  width:300px;
}

a:hover img {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<a href="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png/"><img alt="My Image" border="0" src="https://persagen.com/files/misc/postgres-x_on-pset_align_wrapped.png"></a>
```

Comment: I added some other tips regarding your code as well. Also, not sure if you're interested, but this functionality can be done entirely in CSS, without any need for JavaScript. I have added that to the answer as well.

Comment: That's it -- thank you! I use a lot of images, and use a keygen (a coded keypress) to generate UIDs - hence the function names "gibberish."  Thanks for the solution and tips -- much appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE:  the solution worked well on my local, hand-coded (non-Jekyll) HTML pages; however, in my Jekyll-generated HTML pages, I needed to place `<ul></ul>` or `<div></div>` tags around the JavaScript function (outside the `<script></script>` tags).